# C# console. how to restart an application every 10 minutes?

Tags: c#, bash, mono, console, console-application

I have a C# console application that needs to be restarted every 10 minutes. I was using a batch script to do that till now, but now I need to run this application on linux using mono. Any hints on how to do that?
I don't want to create a bash script for this. Maybe something in my c# code.
I've tried threading, timers and what not.

Comment: Create a cron job to run it every ten minutes.

Comment: cron job is what you need. But do you also need to kill existing instance of the application?

Comment: `*/10 * * * * ./bot.sh` I added this line to the crontab. It looks like its not working.

Comment: An alternative is to keep your application running : insert a System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10*600*1000) in an endless while loop.

Comment: keep running? I want to restart my application after 10 minutes. it should stop after 10 minutes and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cron job to schedule it to run every 10 mins, e.g.:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a Bash script but I think it's a good and quickly solution.

In your crontab add something like :

```
*/10 * * * * /script/pathname.sh
```

On in the general crontab :

```
*/10 * * * * username /script/pathname.sh
```

In the script, write something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash
killall myapp
/usr/bin/myapp
```

Don't forget the sha bang and don't forget to make it executable :

```
chmod u+x /usr/bin/myapp
```

Answer (score -1):

You start new copy of your app and close current.

```
string myApp = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myApp);
    Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: but, how to schedule this after 10 minutes?